# What would happen if a diamagnetic material is placed within a capacitor, instead if a dielectric material?

Tags: capacitor, magnet

In capacitors dielectric materials are sometimes inserted between the parallel plates.  What would happen if a diamagnetic, or a paramagnetic material is inserted between the parallel plates of a capacitor?  How would it change a capacitors ability to allow an AC signal to pass?

Comment: Ask the physics guys or justify why you are asking on EE.

Comment: Unless we moved to a different universe ALL capacitors have a dielectric between conductive plates, even if it is air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these materials, to my knowledge, are good electrical conductors. Which means that you've just replaced your capacitor by a sequence of metal-conductor-metal junctions. In other words, a resistor. It's not a capacitor any more.

For extremely high frequencies, where the dynamic EM field within the diamagnetic material plays a role, this will have very interesting effects that can be better described by microwave components such as circulators, isolators, but your question shows no hint of you being at this level of understanding, so I'd recommend doing a little more material science/physics/RF theory homework first, before approaching these components.

Comment: You did not even mention YIG switches.

Comment: @Sparky256 you've mentioned them, you explain them :) no, seriously, neither YIG nor the typical circulator cores are primarily diamagnetic, but ferromagnetic, if one is honest; to model the (typically low) impact of diamagnetism, however, understanding of the *kind-of opposite effect* does help.